# Does Keras support einsum?

Tags: keras

I tried tf.einsum() in Keras:

```
t1 = Input(...)
t2 = Input(...)
t3 = tf.einsum('ijk,ij->ijk',t1, t2)
model = Model(input=[t1, t2], output=t3)
```

This throws an error, 'AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'. I found that t3 does not have _keras_history and suspect that tf.einsum() is not supported in Keras.

In Keras, Is there anything that is equivalent to einsum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every operation in a keras model must be done inside a keras layer:

```
t3 = Lambda(lambda x: tf.einsum('ijk,ij->ijk',x[0], x[1]))([t1,t2])
```